# Andengine Bluetooth

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to android gaming development. After too much of research I have found Andengine is the best to work with for freshers.
But my game involves connectivity over bluetooth.
Can anyone tell me whether andegine supports bluetooth api or not?
if yes please share the link.

Comment: post question on adengine blog

Comment: i think u want to create a game on the base on bluetooth api so AndEngine is Game Platform in Android and U Have a Android Sdk in Your apps So U Can Use bluetooth api in your app So I This Yourapp=AndEngine+AndroidSdk

Answer (score 1):

I have an Andengine game using bleutooth for multiplayer features. In theory it's fairly easy. You just need to implement it jult like the "bluetooth chat" example. See here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java

And then integrate it to your game. When one player sends a message, the other one will scan the message for possible matches which are mapped to specific actions.

e.g If message = "jump" make call the jump function

You will need to look further into the bluetooth chat example and figure out how to integrate it to your application.